# gnuplot: for and columnheader command

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot, columnheader

I am planning to plot multiple columns data file. draw xy plot with the 1st column and the ith column. so the command for works based on the manual. which gnuplot version begin has such function? my machine install version4.2, but can not work. the same question for columnheader()
i want to make sure it is my code's issue or the version's.

Comment: I think `plot for ...` is available since 4.4, and `do for [...] {...}`, which is more powerful, is available since 4.6.

Comment: @Miguel I wouldn't necessarily say that `do for` is more powerful, because in this situation you *must* use `plot for` ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Version 4.2 already has the `columnheader` function.

Consider the data file `data.txt` which contains

```
first second third fourth
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

In gnuplot 4.2 you can use e.g.

```
set key autotitle columnheader
set style data lines
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4
```

Since version 4.4 you can use iterations inside the `plot` command:

```
set key autotitle columnheader
set style data lines
plot for [i=2:4] 'data.txt' using 1:i
```

Instead of using the `set key autotitle columnheader` you can also use `title columnheader` or `title columnheader(i+1)` if the title column doesn't match the column given in the `using` statement. This also works at least since 4.2.